# Make real formula, conditional formatting and control tip for Shapes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, shapes

three simple quick questions about Shapes in VBA;

1. Is there any way to insert a real formula such as "=Sum(A1:A10)" in Shapes? I could find only to insert a linking cell which is not a real formula.

```
Sub try_shapes()
    With Me.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeBalloon, Left:=100, Top:=10, Width:=60, Height:=30)
        .OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=$A$10" '' only works with a singl linked cell value not a real formula such as "=Sum(A1:A10)"
        .DrawingObject.Formula = "=A10"   '' another way of adding a linked cell with the same limitation
    End With
End Sub
```

2. How to set a conditional formatting for Shapes *in VBA code* when linking to a cell?
3. Is there any control tip for Shapes?
   thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. No, it is not. Only the linked cell can contain a formula which to change the shape Text. 2. A conditional formatting for a shape does not make sense. You can (automatically) modify the shape background, foreground, outline using values of a cell and `Worksheet_Change` event. 3. No, it is not as a shape property. There are some methods using API...

Comment: @FaneDuru  I thought conditional formatting shown on this video might have an equivalent code ;  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o24yr9Oc7l0

Comment: This is not a real conditional formatting. You need a conditional formatted cell to be used in a linked picture. The other method means VBA (the most appropriate should be the change event triggered also by a cell change). You can also use a timer, periodically checking the shape TextArea and change some properties according to these changes. But a timer on the sheet is not really reliable. You may see a lot of screen flickering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the following way:

1. In a worksheet code module copy the next code. The sheet **must be named "ToolT"** and **must contain an ActiveX button, named "CommandButton1"**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const myShape As String = "MyBuble Shape", linkedCell As String = "A10", condForm As String = "A9"

Sub TestShapeOnAction() 'a test macro to be assigned by OnAction
    MsgBox "It works..."
End Sub
Private Sub AddToolTip(ByVal Shp As Shape, ByVal ScreenTip As String)
    Shp.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Shp, "", "", ScreenTip:=ScreenTip
    Shp.AlternativeText = Shp.AlternativeText & "mYScreenTip"
    Set ThisWorkbook.cmb = Application.CommandBars
End Sub

Sub RemoveToolTip()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Shp As Shape
    Set Shp = Me.Shapes(myShape)
    Shp.Hyperlink.Delete
    Shp.AlternativeText = Replace(Shp.AlternativeText, "mYScreenTip", "")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sh As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
      Set Sh = Me.Shapes(myShape)
      If err.Number = 0 Then Sh.Delete 'delete the shape if it exists
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Me.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeBalloon, left:=100, top:=10, width:=60, height:=30)
        .OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=" & linkedCell
        .OnAction = Me.CodeName & ".TestShapeOnAction" 'replace here the macro name with the needed one
        .Name = myShape 'name it
    End With
    Set Sh = Me.Shapes(myShape)
    AddToolTip Shp:=Sh, ScreenTip:="This is a test tooltip..."
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = condForm Then
        Dim Shp As Shape: Set Shp = Me.Shapes(myShape)
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            If Target.Value > 10 Then
                Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Shp.line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.color = vbWhite
            ElseIf Target.Value = 10 Then
                Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Shp.line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.color = vbBlack
            Else
                Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                Shp.line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.color = vbWhite
                Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Else
            Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            Shp.line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.color = vbYellow
            Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   'for the case of an error when cmb object may be lost:
    If ThisWorkbook.cmb Is Nothing Then
        Set ThisWorkbook.cmb = Application.CommandBars
    End If
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next code in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI 'to determine the cursor position
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer


Public WithEvents cmb As CommandBars 'pentru Add_ShapeToolTip module

Private Sub cmb_OnUpdate() 'it is triggered by cursor moving...
    Dim tPt As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos tPt
    If InStr(1, "RangeNothing", TypeName(ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(tPt.x, tPt.y))) = 0 Then
        If ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(tPt.x, tPt.y).OnAction <> "" Then
            If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLButton) Then
                 'this part let the shape using its OnAction set macro:
                Application.Run (ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(tPt.x, tPt.y).OnAction)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 'it removes the tooltip when workbook is closed (not good to have APIs still hanged to not existing objects)
   Dim Sh As Worksheet: Set Sh = Worksheets("ToolT")
   Application.Run Sh.CodeName & ".RemoveToolTip"
End Sub
```

a. Click the ActiveX button and create the balloon shape, allocating a tool tip ("This is a test tooltip...") and setting `OnAction` macro to be run;

b. The shape is linked to the cell "A10". This cell may contain a formula (or not). Changing it, the shape text will be changed accordingly;

5. Cell "A9" will be the one triggering the shape properties: `Fill.ForeColor`, `line.ForeColor`, `Font.Color` and `Bold`. There are three conditions, but they can be a lot more: If "A9" value is numeric (value in "A9" > 10, = 10, `Else`) and if not.

Please, test it and send some feedback. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: thanks, A great thorough demonstration. Let me summarize your answer; 1. Inserting a real formula with functions directly in shapes is not possible, it must be from underlying linked cell. 2. conditional is possible by changing shape's format through Select / Cursor change events . Cursor position change by Windows API is new for me.  3. tooltips can be added by adding Hyperlinks.

Comment: 3. Hyperlihk AND API...

Comment: @FanDuru  One problem I encountered is that when Hyperlink is added to the shape, "OnAction"  does not work any more, even when I added OnAction after Hyperlink line!

Comment: @Leo Sam It looks that `cmb_OnUpdate` is not triggered. This is the part letting the shape to overpass its hyperlink priority.  Let me see why. I am afraid, it cannot work on the sheet code module, if the event is declared in `ThisWorkbook` (It can be declared only there...). I focused only on the tool tip creation and I used the command bar event as I had (and used) it when I tried such an approach. I did not need it, I only experimented to see it working. I will modify the code in a way to accept the shape `OnAction` and I will adapt the above code...

Comment: @@Leo Sam Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.